# Is it possible to use 'index' as a column name in sqlite?

Tags: hibernate, sqlite

Is it possible to use `index` as a column name in sqlite?

When i try to execute this query, it is generate with hibernate/jpa:

```
select
    metadatait0_.id as id25_,
    metadatait0_.guid as guid25_,
    metadatait0_.index as index25_,
    metadatait0_.library_section_id as library7_25_,
    metadatait0_.metadata_type as metadata4_25_,
    metadatait0_.parent_id as parent5_25_,
    metadatait0_.title as title25_ 
from
    metadata_items metadatait0_
```

I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "index": syntax error)
```

Answer (score 8):

Try including column name in square brackets:

```
metadatait0_.[index] as index25_,
```

Answer (score 2):

I would shy away from it; `index` is likely to be a keyword in your RDBMS.  I'd rename it to something else.

This citation says INDEX is a keyword in SQLite:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Comment: I agree, even if it wasn't a reserved keyword, I'd avoid using this name just to be on the safe side.

Comment: The problem that it is used in an existing database (plexapp) which i want to query. So i can't just rename it

Comment: Shouldn't the person that created/maintains that database know about this?  How has it gone undiscovered?